# node: accessing command line arguments from npm scripts and using them from scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I'd like to define the following script in my package.json

```
scripts: {
  "filter": "npm run jest -- -t $1",
  "jest": "jest",
  [...]
```

The idea is that I can run `npm run filter -- my-filter` to execute `npm run jest -- -t my-filter`

If I run:

```
npm run filter -- pattern
-->
npm run jest -- -t $1 "pattern"
```

The $1 is taken literal. If I supres the $1 in my script it works fine, it seems like npm passes all the arguments at the end of the sentence. I just want to know how to work with individual parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like .

```
npm run <command> [-- <args>]
```

For example :-

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "node server.js"
}
```

Then the following commands would be equivalent:

```
node server.js --port=1337 => npm run server -- --port=1337
```

Another **simple** example ,

```
{
  "print": "f(){ echo Hello $1! && echo Bye $2! ;};f",
  "test": "npm run print -- world stranger"
}
```

You get:

```
$ npm test -s # -s is to suppress npm messages for this example
Hello world!
Bye stranger!
```

Hope this code helps you to understand and solve your problem .